# Initializing While Loop

Tags: java, while-loop

I am creating a small program to update an inventory (to either update an existing item in the inventory or add a new item to the inventory). I am able to set up my code but I am not able to step into the while loop for my first two choices. For all three options, I exit my code. Any suggestions on where I am going wrong?

```
public void addinventory items(ArrayList<Inventory> mv) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out
            .println("Choose one of the following menu options (1,2,or 3): \n1. Update an item in the inventory");
    System.out.println("2. Add a new inventory item");
    System.out.println("3. Exit to main menu\n");
    scan.nextInt();

    int choice = 0;
    while (choice == 1) {
        System.out.println("What is the ID of the inventory item?");
        String inventoryID = scan.nextLine();
        while (!checkId(mv, inventoryID)) {
            System.out.println("This ID does not exists, enter a different ID: ");
            inventoryID = scan.nextLine();
        }

        System.out.println("How many inventory items do you wish to add?");
        int numinventory items = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("How many stocks to did you purchase?");
        int num = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("What is the cost of the inventory item?");
        double cost = scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("What is the value of the inventory item?");
        double value = scan.nextDouble();

        //do we need to initiate a new instance of the class? 
        mv.set(numinventory items, null); 
        numinventory items++;
    }

    while (choice == 2) {
        System.out.println("What is the ID of the inventory item?");
        String inventoryID = scan.nextLine();
        while (checkId(mv, inventoryID)) {
            System.out
                    .println("This ID already exists, enter a different ID: ");
            inventoryID = scan.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println("How many inventory items do you wish to add?");
        int numinventory items = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the description?");
        String desc = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("How many stocks to did you purchase?");
        int num = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("What is the cost of the inventory item?");
        double cost = scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("What is the value of the inventory item?");
        double value = scan.nextDouble();

        Inventory inventory = new Inventory(inventoryID.toUpperCase(), desc, num, cost,
                value);

        mv.add(inventory);
        numinventory items--;

    }

    while (choice == 3) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: you probably want `int choice = scan.nextInt();` instead of two statements. Else `choice` is always set to `0`

Comment: you have initialized choice as 0 before while loop, so it will be always 0 ..your code should be like 
int choice= scan.nextInt();

Comment: If you initialize `choice` to zero and then look while it isn't, your loop will never execute. Surely this is obvious?

Answer (score 0):

You set `choice` variable manually. So none of the following while condition will be `true`.

```
int choice = 0;
```

You have to set this choice variable from user input like below

```
int choice = scan.nextInt();
```

Answer (score -1):

You have missed to set the variable `choice`.

When you are scanning the variable you need to store that into `choice` variable to use it.

```
int choice = scan.nextInt();
```

This should work

```
public void addinventory items(ArrayList<Inventory> mv) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out
            .println("Choose one of the following menu options (1,2,or 3): \n1. Update an item in the inventory");
    System.out.println("2. Add a new inventory item");
    System.out.println("3. Exit to main menu\n");
    int choice = scan.nextInt();
    while (choice == 1) {
        System.out.println("What is the ID of the inventory item?");
        String inventoryID = scan.nextLine();
        while (!checkId(mv, inventoryID)) {
            System.out.println("This ID does not exists, enter a different ID: ");
            inventoryID = scan.nextLine();
        }

        System.out.println("How many inventory items do you wish to add?");
        int numinventory items = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("How many stocks to did you purchase?");
        int num = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("What is the cost of the inventory item?");
        double cost = scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("What is the value of the inventory item?");
        double value = scan.nextDouble();

        //do we need to initiate a new instance of the class? 
        mv.set(numinventory items, null); 
        numinventory items++;
    }

    while (choice == 2) {
        System.out.println("What is the ID of the inventory item?");
        String inventoryID = scan.nextLine();
        while (checkId(mv, inventoryID)) {
            System.out
                    .println("This ID already exists, enter a different ID: ");
            inventoryID = scan.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println("How many inventory items do you wish to add?");
        int numinventory items = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the description?");
        String desc = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("How many stocks to did you purchase?");
        int num = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("What is the cost of the inventory item?");
        double cost = scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("What is the value of the inventory item?");
        double value = scan.nextDouble();

        Inventory inventory = new Inventory(inventoryID.toUpperCase(), desc, num, cost,
                value);

        mv.add(inventory);
        numinventory items--;

    }

    while (choice == 3) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```